# HttpContext.Current.Session - Nula

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

Por uma regra de negócio do projeto, sempre que um objeto do tipo `ViewModelBase` é instanciado, preciso realizar algumas validações no perfil do usuário para definir em quais botões o usuário terá acesso na *View* que será carregada.

Para isto, criei dentro do construtor desta classe uma chamada ao método `ObterPermissoes`, que utiliza como base os dados armazenados na sessão do usuário.

O problema é que, toda vez que atualizo alguma DLL no servidor onde a aplicação está publicada (IIS), o valor do objeto desta sessão vem nulo no primeiro acesso dos usuários, gerando exceção na aplicação

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["UsuarioLogado"]
```

O problema é que, no `index` da *View*, o mesmo método é executado e a sessão é carregada normalmente. Porém quando o usuário realiza uma ação de consulta, ao passar pelo método `ObterPermissoes` a sessão está nula, mesmo que anteriormente, para carregar a tela, a informação já tenha sido lida da maneira correta.

Realmente estou bem perdido quanto ao motivo deste erro...

Answer (score 2):

Ao atualizar seu sistema, o IIS expira todas as sessões ativas. Este comportamento é correto e previsto. Não faz sentido manter sessões de uma versão defasada de sistema.

A correção mais simples está em verificar se sua chave não é nula:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UsuarioLogado"] != null) { ... }
```

A correção performática ao seu problema é abandonar permissão por session e [escrever seu próprio atributo de autorização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+authorizeattribute).